# how to get records from database with multi parameters linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

i have a query which gets records from the database, 
i need to pass ids in parameters to call this function,
like Myfunction(1, 2, 3)

i want to get the results which matching with this ids,

like

```
public List<Items> GetItems(int[] ids)
{
var a = from Items in db.item 
where items.id == ids[]
select new Items
{

}
    return a.ToList();
}
```

there is confusion on where clause ( how to get records regarding provided its)

i tried this with looping the ids but could not get any success

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use Contains, method to check. Something similar to Select * from table where Ids in (1,2,3,...)

Try the following.

```
var a = from item in db.Items
        where ids.Contains(item.id)
        select new Item {.....}
```

Where `ids` is your array.

You may see: [Creating IN Queries With Linq To Sql](http://wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 2):

change your code to the following

```
 public List<Items> GetItems(int[] ids)
    {
    var a = from Items in db.item 
    where ids.Contains(Items.id)
    select new Items
    {

    }
        return a.ToList();
    }
```